# Merging lists with unique elements

Tags: haskell

I am trying to combine two lists and remove duplicates.Following is my code but i think i have syntax error and also can anyone suggest a better method to implement this as i am sure there is a better way.

MY CODE

```
combine :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]

combine (x:xs++y:ys)
         |elem x xs || elem x ys = combine xs ++ ys
         |elem y xs || elem y ys = combine xs ++ ys
         |otherwise x:y:combine xs ys
```

I know what the problem wants me to do and  i know how to solve it but i am not able to get over the syntax. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you've defined the type of combine as taking two lists of ints and returning a list of ints, but you're defining combine as taking the combination of two lists.  Also I believe otherwise requires the `=`

```
combine :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
combine x y
  | null x && not (null y) = y
  | null y && not (null x) = x
  | null x && null y = []
  | elem (head x) (tail x) || elem (head x) (tail y) = combine (tail x) y
  | elem (head y) (tail x) || elem (head y) (tail y) = combine x (tail y)
  | (head x) == (head y) = (head x) : combine (tail x) (tail y)
  | otherwise = (head x) : (head y) : combine (tail x) (tail y)
```

This just smells like there's better ways.  There's probably performance gain somewhere (scanning lists multiple times with elem, I'm looking at you).  This code also looks like it's doing a lot of repeating itself too.

A much easier way is by using the nub function in Data.List.

```
import Data.List { nub }
combine:: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
combine x y = nub (x ++ y)
```

After a short `cabal install data-ordlist`:

```
import Data.List.Ordered
combine x y = nubSort $ x ++ y
```

which runs a lot faster.  wee!

Comment: what should the result of `combine [2] [2]` be?

Comment: Good catch, thanks.  Fixed.  Honestly it's a bad idea to implement the notion of distinct-ness along with stitching lists together.  That's part of what made missing this case easier to do than it otherwise would have been.

Comment: since you specialize your type to [Int] (as the OP does as well), there is [a much better alternative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist), exploiting the fact that `Int` is in `Ord`, in addition to being in `Eq`.

Comment: ooooh, nubSort is shiny.  Thanks!  I really don't know anything about just about any module that isn't Prelude.  Really useful to get feedback like this.

Comment: you're welcome. what I had in mind was `union (nubSort xs) (nubSort ys)`. :)